# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

receiving this error when running a spring MVC project in tomcat in Eclipse.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor
```

google has no results regarding the error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven />     
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<context:component-scan base-package="/"></context:component-scan>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" p:maxUploadSize="1000000" />

<bean id="personService" class="PersonService" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="/" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props> 
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManger" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

I've placed cglib-2.2.3.jar in my lib folder but this has made no difference.

I'm at a bit of a loss. I have the class and I understand what the Class is needed for but I don't see how to let spring see this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't have the class, cglib-2.2.3.jar does not contain it.

What version of spring framework are you using? From the XSD I see references to Spring 3.2 which is not released yet. It will be better if you stick to the latest released version (3.1.2)

Comment: I've been using the development release. I'm changing it back to 3.1 as I speak. So it's a different class the one in the cglib jar? Is it meant to be in some spring jar? Which one?

Comment: The file I downloaded from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/cglib/files/latest/download?source=files does not contain the file. As for where it is contained, it is not in the Spring 3.1 jars. It should be in the 3.2 jars, or maybe this error is a bug.

Comment: Oooops, I mean the jar file does not contain the *class*

Answer (score 0):

Since 3.2 M2 Spring doesn't depends from external `cglib` JAR but use its own copy which has renamed to reduce possible clashes with original one.

> As of 3.2 M2, we have upgraded to the new CGLIB 3.0. We repackage all net.sf.cglib classes to org.springframework.cglib and inline them directly within the spring-core JAR. This means that all @Configuration and subclass proxying functionality works out of the box in M2, and means no potential for CGLIB conflicts with other projects.

See following links for more details:

- http://www.springsource.org/node/3654
- https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9669

So, I suppose you have JARs with different Spring version in classpath. Make sure that all of them are 3.2 M2 version.

Comment: I switched back to 3.1, which then gave me all kinds of problems but I ended up writing an interface for my class to implement so I wouldn't need cglib as a workaoround. Thanks for the answer though. Good to know.